# How to match expression of SQL IN operator contain nested braces using regular expression?

Tags: regex

I want to match expression of IN operator in SQL statement.  First, I use

```
(?sUi)\s+in\s*\((.+)\)
```

It can match

```
select * from agent where code in ('abc123', 'a', 'b')
```

and return `'abc123', 'a', 'b'`

But it fails these:

```
select * from agent where code in ('abc123', '(a)', 'b')

select * from agent where code in ('abc123', '(a)))', 'b')

select * from agent where code in ('abc123', '(a)))', 'b') and (code='a()')
```

Comment: which regex flavor?

Comment: Any more test cases, or do you want to match just the strings you supplied?

Comment: Basically, you don't. Any regular expression you come up with will miss something and will be practically unmaintainable. Use a proper parser, you'll be glad you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
(?sUi)\s+in\s*\(((?:[^)']+|'[^']*')*)\)
```

- `[^)']+` anything that is not a close paren or an apostrophe
- `|` or
- `'[^']*'` a string

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lZ6bH7/1)

In SQL Server, apostrophes can be escaped by using two apostrophes in a row:

```
(?sUi)\s+in\s*\(((?:[^)']+|'(?:[^']|'')*')*)\)
```

- `[^)']+` anything that is not a close paren or an apostrophe
- `|` or
- `'(?:[^']|'')*'`

  - an apostrophe followed by

    - anything that is not an apostrophe
    - or a double apostrophe
  - followed by an apostrophe

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lZ6bH7/2)

---

However, the best solution is to use a proper SQL parser/tokenizer.

Comment: Which fails on `select * from agent where code in ('abc123', '(a)\'))', 'b')` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this expression even if you have escaped single apostrophes:

```
(?is)\s+in\s*\(((?:\s*,?\s*'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*')*)\)
```

or to also match alphanumeric values:

```
(?is)\s+in\s*\(((?:\s*,?\s*(?:\w+|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'))*)\)
                              ^^^
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fL1yT5/4)

Note that you do not need the `U` flag since the quantifiers should be greedy.

**Pattern explanation**:

- `(?is)` - make the pattern case insensitive and let `.` match a newline, too
- `\s+in\s*` - 1 or more whitespaces, `in` and 0+ whitespaces
- `\(` - a literal `(`
- `((?:\s*,?\s*(?:\w+|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'))*)` - Group 1 capturing 0 or more occurrences of:

  - `\s*,?\s*` - optional whitespaces (0 or more) followed with an optional comma and 0+ whitespaces
  - `\w+` - 1  or more alphanumeric / underscore symbols
  - `|` - or
  - `'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'` - a single quoted string literal with escaped `'` support
- `\)` -  a literal `)`

Comment: This doesn't allow for capturing numeric values in the parentheses.